# Android find a beacon created using Bluez on Linux

Tags: android, linux, raspberry-pi, beacon, eddystone

Hi I'm trying to connect an Android app to an Eddystone UID Beacon I've created using Bluez 5.23 at a RaspberryPi 3.

The beacon was created using the following command:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig hci0 leadv 3
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1F 02 01 06 03 03 AA FE 17 16 AA FE 00 E7 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 01 02 03 04 05 06 00 00
```

This beacon is apparently working properly cause I can see it in an Android device using some store app like [Beacon Toy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uriio&hl=en).

I am using the following code inside the Main Activity in order to discover the beacon:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BeaconConsumer, MonitorNotifier {
...
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this.getApplicationContext());
    beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
            setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
    beaconManager.bind(this);
}

@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    Region region = new Region("my-beacon-region", null, null, null);
    beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
    try {
        beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
    Log.d(TAG, "I detected a beacon in the region with namespace id " + region.getId1() +
            " and instance id: " + region.getId2());
}
}
```

Anyone knows what might be happening? The method `didEnterRegion` is never called. I also put a 'didDetermineStateForRegion' method inside the class but I always receive `OUTSIDE` in the state param meaning that I'm not in the region.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you did not request or did not approve the Bluetooth and Location permissions for your application. Look at: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/requesting_permission.html.

If you have the correct permissions already then few questions to be sure:
Is the beacon recognized as **Eddystone UID** by the Beacon Toy app?
Is onBeaconServiceConnect called?

A small hint: I recommend you to initialize the BeaconManager in onCreate method instead of onResume. You are adding new parser whenever your app is resumed right now. I am actually doing this in application object as even onCreate of activity can be called multiple times.

Comment: I agree ensuring Bluetooth permission is granted is key.  Otherwise your app cannot detect and you will always be outside.